# How to request nearby devices android 12 in react native?

Tags: android, react-native, android-12

How to check permission nearby device in android 12 react native?

like this image
[image]

Comment: wouldn't the user have to do that?

Comment: Yes, but i need to check permission form my app did user granted the access or not with react native @IndexZero

Comment: Why would it be different from checking if a read or write external storage is granted? You request it in the same way too, or not?

Answer (score 0):

I must use request multiple from react-native-permissions

example code

```
requestMultiple(bluetoothPermission).then((result) => {
            if (result[bluetoothPermissionResult] === RESULTS.GRANTED || result[bluetoothPermissionResult] === RESULTS.UNAVAILABLE) {
                //so something
            } else if (result[bluetoothPermissionResult] === RESULTS.BLOCKED || result[bluetoothPermissionResult] === RESULTS.DENIED) {
//do something
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
        })
```